# Redirecting in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, redirect

I am having an issue regarding navigation in my SharePoint site. On my front page I have a link that takes you to the `EditForm.aspx` of one of my lists. When I edit an element and click save, SharePoint takes me to the list. Instead I want it to take me back to the default page, where I came from.

Is there any way to redirect back to the page I initially came from, instead of going back to the list?

Comment: Consider writing the solution as a real answer and marking it as accepted (so the information is here and readers don't have to rely on an external site, which may go down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! http://www.graphicalwonder.com/?p=666

Use '?source=' in your anchor tag url, that way it will return to the source site, rather than back to the list.

Ex: http://yoursite/yourlist/newform.aspx?source=http://yoursite/yourlibrary/thankyou.aspx

Works perfectly!